# MongoDb : How to insert additional object into object collection in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

**I want just push object into array of objects in mongodb**

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51c9cf2b206dfb73d666ae07"),
    "firstName" : "john",
    "lastName" : "smith",
    "ownerEmail" : "john.smith@gmail.com",
    "camps" : [
            {
                    "name" : "cubs-killeen",
                    "location" : "killeen"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "cubs-temple",
                    "location" : "temple"
            }
    ],
    "instructors" : [
            {
                    "firstName" : "joe",
                    "lastName" : "black"
            },
            {
                    "firstName" : "will",
                    "lastName" : "smith"
            }
    ]
}
```

and to push object into above document in need to do

```
db.stack.update({"ownerEmail":"john.smith@gmail.com"}, 
             {$push: { 
                        "camps":{ "name":"cubs-killeen","location":"some other Place" } 
                      }
             }
             )
```

So how can i implement same functionality using **mgo driver**

Comment: There is no need to [prefix question titles with their tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), please edit the title. Also, please do not abuse **bold** markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer session.Close()

session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

// Drop Database
if IsDrop {
    err = session.DB("test").DropDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

// Collection Stack
c := session.DB("test").C("stack")

// Query
query := bson.M{"ownerEmail": "john.smith@gmail.com"}
update := bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"camps": bson.M{"name": "cubs-killeen", "location": "some other Place"}}}

// Update
err = c.Update(query, update)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: thanx for clarified ans

Comment: @AkashShinde No worries :-)

Comment: above method is adding element as array

Comment: @AkashShinde I thought in your question that's the update you wanted. The [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator appends a specified value to an array. Consider using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator, it adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) does nothing to that array.

Comment: sorry your code working fine, i did mistake , i was appending array to array

Answer (score 2):

I assume your codebase has **Camps** struct similar to:

```
type Camps struct {
    Name     string   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Location string   `json:"location,omitempty"`
 }
```

Golang code:

```
database := "yourDatabaseName"  
collection := "stack"

session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
defer session.Close()

session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
c := session.DB(database).C(collection)

data := model.Camps{
        Name:       "cubs-killeen",
        Location:   "some other Place",
   }
selector := bson.M{"ownerEmail": "john.smith@gmail.com"}
changes := bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"camps": bson.M{"$each": []model.Camps{data}}}}
err = c.Update(selector, changes)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
```