# How would I go about inserting a subdocument in Mongodb in Golang / mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Say for example I had the following struct:

```
type Article struct {
    Title string `form"title" json:"title"`
    Categories []*Category 
}
```

How would I go about adding a new category?

Comment: I believe the db driver would add whatever sub documents are reflected in your model. Meaning, if you have items in `Categories` and you make correct use of tags for mongo (requires bson attribute I believe) then it should just take care of it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb : How to insert additional object into object collection in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817535/mongodb-how-to-insert-additional-object-into-object-collection-in-golang)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it using:

```
change := mgo.Change{
    Update: bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"categories": cat}},
}

_, err := repo.collection.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(article)).Apply(change, nil)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the **Article** struct as :

```
type Article struct {
   ArticleId  string      `bson:"_id"`
   Title      string      `form"title" json:"title,omitempty"`
   Categories []Category  `json:"category,omitempty"`
}
```

Your Query accordingly:

```
data := model.Category{
            CategoryId :      "yourText",
            Product    :      "productName,
             ...
        }

selector := bson.M{"_id": "provideTheTitle"}
changes := bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"category": bson.M{"$each": []model.Category{data}}}}
err = c.Update(selector, changes)
```

It would be great if you can share your ***Category*** struct and include an field **_id** in your Article struct.